# Assigning specific things to a class in Python

Tags: class, python-2.7

Ok this is a pretty basic question, but I am trying to improve the efficiency of my code. I have a text-based game, and I currently have a separate class for every weapon that I have, each with independently operated variables. I'm using the Python 2.7 IDE. This is what my code looks like: (Also, how would I reference the properties of each weapon?)

```
class Weapon1():
owned = True
damage = 2
accuracy = 75

class Weapon2():
owned = False
damage = 4
price = 50
accuracy = 95

class Weapon3():
owned = False
damage = 8
price = 250
accuracy = 50

class Weapon4():
owned = False
damage = 10
price = 500
accuracy = 60

class Weapon5():
owned = False
damage = 10
price = 500
accuracy = 60
```

Comment: What exactly is the basic question you are asking?  (And how did this already get 2 upvotes?)

Comment: I want to make this more efficient, by combining these into one class, if possible. About the upvotes? I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one `Weapon` class, and then have the different types of weapons be instances of that class. The below implementation assumes you give every weapon a `price` attribute.

```
class Weapon(object):

    def __init__(self, owned, damage, price, accuracy):
        self.owned = owned
        self.damage = damage
        self.price = price
        self.accuracy = accuracy


weapon1 = Weapon(
    owned = True,
    damage = 2,
    price = None,
    accuracy = 75
)

weapon2 = Weapon(
    owned = False,
    damage = 4,
    price = 50,
    accuracy = 50
)

...
```

and so on, for all your weapons. Then you can access the attributes of individual instances like below.

```
>>> weapon2.accuracy
95
>>> weapon1.owned
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Weapon(object):
    def __init__(self, owned, damage, price, accuracy):
        self.owned = owned
        self.damage = damage
        self.price = price
        self.accuracy = accuracy
    def __repr__(self):
        guts = ', '.join('{0}={1!r}'.format(k,v) for k,v in self.__dict__.items())
        return '{0}({1})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, guts)


weapons = [
    Weapon(owned=True,  damage=2,  price=None, accuracy=75),
    Weapon(owned=False, damage=4,  price=50,   accuracy=95),
    Weapon(owned=False, damage=8,  price=250,  accuracy=50),
    Weapon(owned=False, damage=10, price=500,  accuracy=60),
    Weapon(owned=False, damage=10, price=500,  accuracy=60),
]

for i, w in enumerate(weapons, start=1):
    print i, w


# to access individual properties
wielded = weapons[0]
print "damage of wielded weapon:", wielded.damage
```

Gives:

```
1 Weapon(price=None, damage=2, owned=True, accuracy=75)
2 Weapon(price=50, damage=4, owned=False, accuracy=95)
3 Weapon(price=250, damage=8, owned=False, accuracy=50)
4 Weapon(price=500, damage=10, owned=False, accuracy=60)
5 Weapon(price=500, damage=10, owned=False, accuracy=60)

damage of wielded weapon: 2
```